how to load lazily loaded route in mat-sidebar-content?
I've a structure in Angular and we are following module based structure. Not standalone components.
SideBar Component
<mat-sidebar-container>
<mat-sidebar>
/* Sidebar Menu Items */
</mat-sidebar>
<mat-sidebar-content>
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidebar-content>
</mat-sidebar-container>

the side bar component's app selector is 
Side bar is not lazily loaded/ loaded with app.module
Header Component
Header component is added in sidebar content as shown above and it's app selector is shown below which is loaded with app.module.ts / not lazy loaded

I've multiple routes/modules which are lazily loaded like order, customer, reports etc. and in all the modules the structure will remain same of side bar as shown above.. sidebar including header component.so whatever new route I'll be loading I'll have to add it's app selector inside mat-sidebar-content.
consider an example of reports module..
{
  route: 'reports',
loadChildren: import('...../reports.module').then(m => m.reportsModule),
authGuard: [AuthGuard]
}

My question is how do I keep same side bar structure so that any newly added route/ module can be added under app-header in sidebar component as shown below after laziy loading route. What are the ways to implement this scenario?
reports.component.html
Either something like this
**<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<app-reportChildComponent></app-reportsChildComponent>**

or any other way. structure should remain same.
<mat-sidebar-container>
<mat-sidebar>
/* Sidebar Menu Items */
</mat-sidebar>
<mat-sidebar-content>
<app-header></app-header>
<app-reports></app-reports>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidebar-content>
</mat-sidebar-container>

Sidebar is on the left side of page. Header is on the top of the page.
Sidebar should slide over header bar and any other component that



How to load other modules lazily and add lazily loaded modules in same structure with app-sidebar selector and pass new routes/modules app selector in the place of sidebar content.
